# user auth template tags not working-Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication

I used django-registration app. Everything goes fine. User gets registered with email verification but when user logs in and is redirected to mainpage the auth template tags such as {% if user.is_authenticated %} returns false.

I am having this in my login.html

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
```

After login I want to redirect the user to main page and in mainpage.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>  
{% endif %}
```

but user.is_authenticated returns false here. What might be the problem here? Thanks

Comment: are you passing in the user object correctly? That could cause it to return as false

Answer (score 2):

Try using `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` instead. It's entirely possible that user isn't being passed into the context dictionary within the view. If the object is not found within the template, it will just skip to the else portion of the block. Rendering templates are strange in django, as what would normally be an exception, is swallowed.

Comment: i am using django.contrib.auth.login view. and i think they do pass user in their context dictionary. ?

Comment: @Nazim, did you try request.user?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code for the view which handles the URL '/'? I think this is where your problem lies, rather than in your use of django-registration.

Does this view put `user` in the context? If you want to use it in the template, you're going to have to put it in. If you want to use `request` in the context, then you need to make sure that you pass an instance of `RequestContext` as the context rather than just a standard context object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

Suppose your `main page` gets processed by a view in `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def mainpage(request):
    return render_to_response('mainpage.html')
```

You need to add RequestContext to include to user object.  Change your view to

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def mainpage(request):
    return render_to_response('mainpage.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```